# Como definir a variável db no ClienteModel?

Tags: php, mvc

Estou engatinhando em MVC e estou apanhando em um 'simples' cadastro. Ao clicar em cadastrar, aparece os erros:

> Notice: Undefined variable: **db** in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastromvc\App\Models\ClienteModel.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function **prepare()** on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastromvc\App\Models\ClienteModel.php on line 9

Na index.php chamo o config, não sei se o erro tem relação a conexão com o banco.

Projeto completo, caso for necessário: https://github.com/JonathanSilvaTI/cadastromvc

*Model.php*

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Models;

    class Model
    {
        protected $db;

        public function __construct(\PDO $db){
            $this->db = $db;
        }
    }
```

*ClienteModel.php*

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Models;
    use Application\Models\Model;

    class ClienteModel extends Model
    {
        // Verifica se o Usuário já existe
        public static function existeUsuario($usuario){
            $verificaUsuario = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `loja_clientes` WHERE `usuario` = :usuario");
            $verificaUsuario->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $verificaUsuario->execute();
            if($verificaUsuario->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Verifica se o CPF já existe
        public static function existeCPF($cpf){
            $verificaCPF = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `loja_clientes` WHERE `cpf` = :cpf");
            $verificaCPF->bindValue(':cpf', $cpf, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $verificaCPF->execute();
            if($verificaCPF->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Cadastro de usuário
        public static function cadastrar($dados){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `loja_clientes` (nome, email, cpf, usuario, senha) 
                    VALUES (:nome, :email, :cpf, :usuario, :senha)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(":nome", $dados['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":email", $dados['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":cpf", $dados['cpf'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":usuario", $dados['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":senha", $dados['senha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A varíavel **`$db`** não está sendo instanciada.

Comment: Você usa `static` porque? e no caso de acesso `$this->db` se for instâncias de classe talvez até tenha que mudar o jeito de fazer! Tem erros conceituais

Answer (score 2):

Para acessar `protected $db` da sua classe base retire `static` dos métodos da classe `ClienteModel` e faça o acesso com `$this->db`:

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Models;

    class Model
    {
        protected $db;

        public function __construct(\PDO $db){
            $this->db = $db;
        }
    }
```

---

Não esqueça de criar o *construtor* nas `ClienteModel` passando o valor do `PDO` e acesse sempre com `$this->db` no qual seu código está somente `$db`.

```
class ClienteModel extends Model
{
    public function __construct(\PDO $db)
    {
        parent::__construct($db);
    }

    // Verifica se o Usuário já existe
    public function existeUsuario($usuario)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `loja_clientes` WHERE `usuario` = :usuario";
        $verificaUsuario = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $verificaUsuario->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $verificaUsuario->execute();
        if($verificaUsuario->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Trabalhe nesse caso com instâncias:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=BANCO;charset=UTF8;',
        'root',
        'password');
$clienteModel = new ClienteModel($db);
```

Esse código reflete os problemas encontradas na sua pergunta, claro que isso pode ser ainda melhorado, mas, me limitei a passar o seu problema a limpo.

Comment: Acho que estou esquecendo de algo. Informa o erro: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context - quando acesso com $this->db-prepare()

Comment: @JonathanSilva você removeu `static` dos métodos, exemplo: `public function existeUsuario($usuario)`

Comment: sim, mesmo assim, me deparei com esse erro

Comment: `$this->db->prepare() ` tente assim faltou um flecha, é erro de digitação ou não carregou a classe PDO

Comment: errei na hora de digitar por aqui, mas esta OK no codigo

Comment: ou não carregou a classe PDO

Comment: não entendi, no ClienteModel eu criei construtor, como você havia sugerido

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51686/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-jonathan-silva).